# Add-AlertRule command not recoganised

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-application-insights

I get the following error when I run Add-AlertRule. I have logged in as Login-AzureRmAccount and even Get-AzureRmResource works.I am on windows10. Installed azure powershell *version 1.6*

**Add-AlertRule : The term 'Add-AlertRule' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

```
Add-AlertRule  -Name $alertName -Description $description `
 -ResourceGroup $resourceGroup `
 -ResourceId "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourcegroups/$resourceGroup/providers/microsoft.insights/components/$appInsightName" `
 -MetricName $metricName `
 -Operator GreaterThan  `
 -Threshold $threshold   `
 -WindowSize $windowSize  `
 -SendToServiceOwners `
 -Location "East US" `
 -CustomEmails 'DavidChew@Contoso.com','PattiFuller@Contoso.com'
 -RuleType Metric
```

Comment: Did you also `Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager`?

Comment: Two things. What version of Azure Powershell are you using? Can you post the entire command you're attempting to execute? There are two replacements `Add-AzureRmMetricAlertRule` and `Add-AzureRmWebtestAlertRule` and you might need to use those

Comment: @BrendanGreen `Switch-AzureMode` was deprecated almost a year ago.

Comment: I have updated the post with version and sample code I used. After your suggestion I tried to use Add-AzureRMMetricAlertRule but i do not see -SendToServiceOwners or -CustomEmails option. I am trying to add alert in Application Insights. Suggestions?Add-AlertRule used to work but I think things have changed with the latest version.

Comment: @DavidMakogon oh - sourced from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-powershell-alerts/ - a document that was last updated less than 4 months ago...